# Insert and retrieve image from database wpf c#

Tags: c#, database, wpf, image, byte

I would like to insert image to my database. After clicking button the image should be retrieved from database and showed. How to do it?

Thats what I am sending to database:

```
    //Send my img
    private void SendImageMessageClicked(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
       OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        openFileDialog.Filter = "Images PNG (.png)|*.png";
        if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            string message = imageToByteArray(System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(openFileDialog.FileName)).ToString();

            if (con.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
                con.Close();

            con.Open();
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO messages VALUES(null, " + userId + ", " + secondUserId + ", '" + message + "', '" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") + "')";
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            writeMessage.Text = "";
            con.Close();
        }
    }

    // convert image to byte array
    public byte[] imageToByteArray(System.Drawing.Image imageIn)
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        imageIn.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
```

That is how I am trying to get it back:

```
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
            MemoryStream stream;

            stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes((string)dr[3]));
            image.BeginInit();
            image.StreamSource = stream;
            image.EndInit();

            imgMsg.Source = image;
        }
```

Comment: Why are you ASCII encoding the data?

Comment: You'll find a full example [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/354639/Storing-and-Retrieving-Images-from-SQL-Server-Us-2)

Comment: @McNets do answer in full (and perhaps with link, but not needed) why you think that would be a full example (did not look at link - but suggestion for answer)

Comment: It makes no sense to decode an image from file just to get back an encoded frame buffer. Just read the binary file content by `File.ReadAllBytes(openFileDialog.FileName)` and write that to the database. When you create a a BitmapImage from a Stream, make sure to close the Stream after decoding by putting it in a `using` block. You also have to set `image.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;`

Answer (score -1):

this is example code, how to `INSERT` image (u should use `VARBINARY(MAX)` type in column):

```cs
                 Image image = Image.FromFile(@"D:\test\pictures\react-redux.png");
                 byte[] imageAsByteArr = ImageToByteArray(image);
                 using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("insert into ImageTable values(2,@binaryValue)", conn))
                 {
                     command.Parameters.Add("@binaryValue", SqlDbType.VarBinary, imageAsByteArr.Length).Value = imageAsByteArr;
                     command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                 }
```

code above is using `ImageToByteArray(...)`:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3801289/12262729

when it comes to retrieve this data, let read this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7724595/12262729

after u retrieved data, let convert it to image:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27774058/12262729